# When two resolutions of coherent sheaves are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on a projective manifold $X$. It is well known that one can construct a resolution of $\mathcal{F}$ by holomorphic vector bundles (locally free sheaves).

Are two such resolutions homotopic? Any reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Crossposted at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408495/when-are-two-resolutions-of-a-coherent-sheaf-homotopic) at the same time it was posted here. Please see [meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/) for site rules about cross-posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think not only can two such resolutions not be homotopy equivalent, but there might be no non-zero maps between them at all.

One way to construct a resolution of a coherent sheaf on a projective scheme is to use Serre's theorem. Take a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a Noetherian projective scheme $X$, multiply it by $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$, for large enough $n$ it is globally generated, you surject on it from a direct sum of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and twist back. The beginning of your resolution then looks like $$\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus s}(-n)\to\mathcal{F}\to0.$$

But if I take a greater twist, i.e. some $\mathcal{F}(m)$, $m>n$. I get a resolution starting with $$\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r}(-m)\to\mathcal{F}\to0.$$

But there are simply no non-zero morphisms from $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus s}(-n)$ to $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r}(-m)$ in this case.

So no, I don't think there is a canonical choice of a locally free resolution in the homotopy category of coherent sheaves. There is, however, a canonical flat resolution on, I think, any scheme. A reference that was hugely useful for me is [these notes by Daniel Murfet](http://therisingsea.org/notes/DerivedCategoriesOfSheaves.pdf).